# ¿Por qué se le dice "camisa" a la menstruación?

Tags: etimología, historia, palabras-raras

La acepción 14 de [**camisa**](https://dle.rae.es/camisa) es:

> 14. f. p. us. menstruo (‖ acción de menstruar).

Por lo que he podido encontrar, aparece al menos desde el DLE de 1780, con la marca de **ant.**:

> CAMISA. ant. El menstruo, ó regla de las mugeres. Hoy tiene uso en algunas partes. *Menstrua*.

¿Qué relación hay entre la camisa y la menstruación, como para tenga esa acepción?

Answer (score 2):

Hay que irse muy atrás para encontrar una explicación, pero afortunadamente en este caso el amigo Covarrubias nos saca de dudas. Dice lo siguiente en su *Tesoro* de 1611:

> Mudar camisa, tomarla limpia: y los trabajadores que estan a jornal toda la semana, dizen que van el sabado a mudar camisa.

Nótese que la camisa entonces se refería a la prenda que se llevaba pegada a la piel, bajo las demás capas de ropa, de hecho dejar a alguien en camisa era sinónimo de desnudarlo. Más adelante dice:

> Estar la muger con su camisa, estar con su regla, o menstruo, porque no la ha de mudar hasta que de todo se le aya acabado la purgacion, y las que por muy limpias lo han hecho, les ha costado caro, y a muchas la vida.

Desde luego, la vida de las mujeres no debía de ser nada fácil hacia los siglos XVI y XVII, épocas donde he visto textos que se referían a la menstruación con este término. Por tanto, la acepción viene de la costumbre de no cambiarse las mujeres la camisa mientras estaban con el periodo. Si en el *Autoridades* del siglo XVIII ya se marcaba la voz como antigua, esperemos que eso significara que ya por entonces las dejaran cambiarse de camisa al menos.

Comment: Hay algún lugar donde aun se use la palabra "camisa" para indicar "menstruación"?

Comment: Me viene a la cabeza que esto fue escrito por un hombre. Que la camisa se referia a la prenda, muy bien. Que las mujeres no la cambiaban hasta se terminar la cuestión me parece un "poco demasiado".

Comment: @Lambie por supuesto que fue escrito por un hombre: Sebastián de Covarrubias. Su _Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española_ fue publicado en 1611. Ignoro si lo que escribió sobre la camisa era una creencia suya, o si de verdad se hacía así (me creo cualquier cosa). Pero al menos explica el origen de la acepción de _camisa_.

Comment: Charlie, estás repetiendo lo que dije. Sí, claro, explica lo que es la prenda. Sé quien es.

Comment: @Lambie lo siento, he debido de malinterpretar tu comentario de "me viene a la cabeza que...", pensaba que lo decías como una suposición.

Comment: Sí, lo es. La suposición era  en relación al "no mudar", no la prendra en si.